# Split Background Color HTML

Tags: html, css

So, I understand that this is the code for splitting the background in two colors:

```
#top,
#bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50%;
}

#top {
    top: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

The source of this can be visualized here: http://dabblet.com/gist/2870276.

On my website, rather than 50% and 50%, I have 30% and 70%. How do I make it so that when the browser is adjusted to shrink horizontally, the top 30% doesn't stay at 30% but at the height of the original?

Comment: You want a minimum height for the top?

Answer (score 13):

I suggest using a gradient instead of document elements for background effects like this.

Try this:

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, orange 50%, green 50%, green);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Note that you'll need to make the `body` element fill the page:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my example: http://dabblet.com/gist/4ba4bde188af953dcdcc

That said, I don't understand what you mean by "shrinking horizontally" or "height of the original" - I hope I've answered what you're looking for.

#### Update:

According to Albert in the comments the OP wants the 30% to be relative to the height of the viewport when the page is loaded. This is doable, but must be done through JavaScript. I'll give a pure JS implementation without using jQuery.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setBodyGradientOnLoad);

function setBodyGradientOnLoad() {
    var heightPx = window.innerHeight;
    var gradientStop = Math.floor( heightPx * 0.3 );
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, orange " + gradientStop + "px, green " + gradientStop + "px, green)";
}
```

Note that you still need the rest of the CSS to apply the `background-size` and `background-repeat` options, as well as to provide a fallback for browsers with JavasScript disabled.

Note that my use of "`DOMContentLoaded`" and the un-prefixed `linear-gradient` means this will only work in modern browsers (IE 9+, Safari 3.1+ - 2010 or later, basically)

Comment: Your code provides the same result as his... He wants the height and width to be 50% when the webpage is first loaded, but then to be locked in at it's value and no longer be dynamic... so if the web view is scaled down in height, the background color sections don't change in size with it.

Comment: Basically he wants to set the height to a PIXEL value, not a PERCENT value... but he wants that pixel value to be whatever 50% of the initial web view height is when the page first loads.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw you would have to do that using JavaScript to capture the initial viewport dimensions,. Fortunately JavaScript can be used to generate the gradient after the viewport size is known.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I have updated my question with a solution to your interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to not use two elements to do so. Only use one and set a "split background-color" like so. By the way, doing this purely with CSS will make it responsive to all screen resizing.

I solved this purely with CSS, and with NO EXTRA DOM ELEMENTS! This means that the two colors are purely that, just background colors of ONE ELEMENT, not the background color of two.

I used a gradient and, becuase I set the color stops so closely together, it looks as if the colors are distinct and that they do not blend.

Here is the gradient in native syntax:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
```

Color `#74ABDD` starts at `0%` and is still `#74ABDD` at `49.9%`.

Then, I force the gradient to shift to my next color within `0.2%` of the elements height, creating what appears to be a very solid line between the two colors.

Here is the outcome:

[image: Split Background Color]

And **[here's my JSFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/eg8e3n0x/)**

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Just use Javascript! Convert the "%" to "#pixels" right when the page loads, and then never convert it again, so that even when the user adjusts the size of their page, the height is constant, 30% of what the original height of the page was, not the new height of the page.

(*Note: This won't work on Dabblet.com since it doesn't support Javascript.. here is a JSFiddle version of it operational. http://jsfiddle.net/x35o09m1/ )

```
<html>
<head>

<div id="bottom" style="position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height:100%; background-color: green;">bottom - 70%</div>
<div id="top" style="position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; background-color: orange;">top - 30%</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

    document.getElementById("top").style.height = (y*0.3)+"px";

</script>


</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use pixels instead of percentages if you want to keep a particular background color fixed.  If its a navigation section you're trying to keep fixed in place, though, you can also use Bootstrap.  Here is an example of a fixed nav block:  http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/

Answer (score 0):

I will go on and answer the question, affecting the OP code minimally:

```
#top{       
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30%;
}
#bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70%;
}

#top {
    top: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```